# Symfony2 Split Variable

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I'm working on a Symfony2 project, but this question probably still applies to just general php. I'm still very much learning.

I have a url that needs to like `website.com/2014/fall/other`. In symfony's twig template I have the links as `website.com/{{ allSemesters }}/other`

The variables I'm passing in are

```
$allSemesters=array("Fall 2014", "Spring 2015", "Summer 2015");
```

This is in my template.

```
{% for allSemester in allSemesters %}
    <a href="{{ allSemester }}/other">{{ allSemester | capitalize }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Resulting in links that go to: `website.com/Spring%202015/other` and not `website.com/2015/Spring/other`.

Any way to reconfigure my array or split the variable somehow to get the desired url? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use twig's [replace](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter

```
 <a href="{{ allSemester |replace({' ': "/"}) }}/other">
```

The "Symfony way" would be to use [path()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) to calculate the route given a 'season' and 'year' parameter

Comment: Yes, I guess I should probably do this the proper way and pass the variables through the symfony path(). Good call, and thanks for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using .yml routing, I would do something like this:

```
semester_other:
    pattern: /{year}/{semester}/other/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBlablaBundle:Semester:other", year: null, semester: null}
```

And the controller:

```
public function otherAction($year, $semester) {

}
```